# Bayes Linear Regression - understanding the posterior formula?

Tags: regression, bayesian, conditional-probability

In the linked [resource](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-bayesian-linear-regression-e66e60791ea7), the author defines the posterior probability of Bayesian linear regression as:

```
P(B|y,X) = P(y|B,X)*P(B|X)/P(y|X)
```

I have a couple questions/issues with this.

First, B represents the weight(s) vector, but it shouldn't include the bias term, b, in `y=mx+b`. Does this model just forget to include a bias or is it somehow factored in B?

Second, I'm used to seeing Bayes Rule in a very specific form:

```
P(A|B) = P(B|A)*P(A)/P(B)
```

So it's my naive guess that the posterior would take the following form:

```
P(B|y,X) = P(y,X|B)*P(B)/P(y,X)
```

Do the equations, mine & the source, equate to the same value? If not, why am I wrong? I gather that there is something about conditional probabilities and the chain rule that is going over my head.

**EDIT**: According to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzZ5b3wdZQk) my interpretation is correct! However, I'm still unclear where the bias term comes into play. Likewise, I'd like to what likelihood and priors are typically used. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression) shows:
[image: likelihood]

This looks somewhat like a multivariate guassian, without some scaling terms outside of the exponent, and most notably, no precision matrix (aka inverse covariance) in the exponentiated term.

Does this likelihood have a name? Where did it come from? Etc.

Comment: Include the unit vector as a column of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote from our [Bayesian Essentials with R](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461486862) book (Chapter 3, p.67):

> The *ordinary normal linear regression* model is such that $$ \mathbf
>  y|\beta,\sigma^2,X\sim\mathscr{N}_n(X\beta,\sigma^2I_n) \tag{1}$$ and thus $$
>  \mathbb{E}[y_i|\beta,X]=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{i1}+\ldots+\beta_kx_{ik}\,,\quad
>  \mathbb{V}(y_i|\sigma^2,X)=\sigma^2\,. $$ In particular, the presence
> of an *intercept* $\beta_0$ explains why a column of $1$'s is
> necessary in the matrix $X$ to preserve the compact formula $X\beta$ in the conditional mean of $\mathbf y$.

for the inclusion of an intercept in the regression and (Chapter 3, p.66)

> A large proportion of statistical analyses deal with the
> representation of dependences among several observed quantities.
> For instance, which social factors influence unemployment
> duration and the probability of finding a new job? Which economic
> indicators are best related to recession occurrences? Which
> physiological levels are most strongly correlated with aneurysm
> strokes? From a statistical point of view, the ultimate goal of these
> analyses is thus to find a proper representation of the conditional
> distribution, $f(y|\theta,\mathbf x)$, of an observable variable $y$ given a
> vector of observables $\mathbf x$, based on a sample of $\mathbf x$ and $y$.

to stress that the entire analysis is run *conditional on $\mathbf X$*. With a further excerpt (Chapter 3, p.72):

> We stress here that conditioning on $\mathbf X$ is valid only when $\mathbf X$ is exogenous, that is, only when we can write the joint distribution of $(\mathbf y,\mathbf X)$ as
> $$
> f(\mathbf y,\mathbf X|\alpha,\beta,\sigma^2,\delta)=f(\mathbf y|\alpha,\beta,\sigma^2,\mathbf X)f(\mathbf X|\delta)\,,
> $$
> where $(\alpha,\beta,\sigma^2)$ and $\delta$ are fixed parameters. We can
> thus ignore $f(\mathbf X|\delta)$ if the parameter $\delta$ is only a
> nuisance parameter since this part is independent of
> $(\alpha,\beta,\sigma^2)$. The practical advantage of using a regression
> model as above is that it is much easier to specify a realistic
> conditional distribution of one variable given $p$ others rather than a
> joint distribution on all $p+1$ variables. Note that if $\mathbf X$ is not
> exogenous, for instance when $\mathbf X$ involves past values of $\mathbf y$,the joint distribution must be used instead.

Concerning the likelihood function, it stems from (1) with $\mathbf y$ being indeed a Normal vector with $\sigma^2 \mathbf I_n$ as its covariance matrix. This follows from the Normality assumption on the noise $\mathbf \epsilon$.